# What happens to answers if they are deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I read the question on [What is the best way to handle product versioning and branching of long term projects?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129543/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-product-versioning-and-branching-of-long-term-pro)

I saw all the answers but I wanted to make a value edition to it by [proving the a support answer relevant to the question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/133947/40327) but I was down voted for the same. When I deleted it it still remains there to be marked in red stating "deleted by owner X hours ago".

May I understand the logic behind why my answer not getting removed completely ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost everything in Stack Exchange has an undo for transparency purposes: for example, many posts can be deleted by the community as part of our community moderation process. Being able to see the deleted posts and undelete it helps keep that in check.

But deleted posts are generally not available to the public, even though it might look like it at first blush. The only people who can see it are:

- You, because it's your post
- People with over 10k reputation, because they have the ability to vote to undelete posts
- Community-elected moderators, like me
- Stack Exchange employees

Comment: Thanks Mark. I was completely dejected when I was down voted for contributing to the good cause but I have read one of your posts which says being down voted is part of the process. Because in FAQ they say that if your answer is relevant to the question even through it is from another author it is not completely incorrect to put it as an answer by providing a link.

Comment: Mark I just have another query. What I would like to learn from that mistake. What must I learn from my experience relating to my answer as I do not want to repeat this mistake again.

Comment: @Karthik Let's [talk about it in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21)